# Thread-safe inheritance

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot

I create a hierarchy from an abstract class and two children that are used in class F and pass them to the service

```java
@Getter    
abstract class A {

    private final B b;
       
    public A(B b) {
    
        this.b = b;
    
    }
   
    abstract void doSomething();
    
}

@Getter
class B {

    private final String someProperty;

}

class C extends A {

    public C(B b) {

        super(b);

    }

    @Override
    void doSomething() {

       super.getb().getSomeProperty();

    }

}

class D extends A {

    public D(B b) {
    
        super(b);
    
    }

    @Override
    void doSomething() {
    
        super.getb().getSomeProperty();
    
    }  

}

@RestController
class F {

    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    @GetMapping
    public void methodOne() {

        A a1 = new C(new B("ccc"));
        service.make(a1);

    }  
    
    @GetMapping
    public void methodTwo() {
    
        A a1 = new D(new B("ddd"));
        service.make(a1);
    
    }

}

@Service
public class Service {

    public void make(A a) {
    
        a.doSomething();

    }
    
}
```

The construction that I described above in case we have a lot of clients who call our API will there be any problems in thread safety with the state of our abstract class or not?

Comment: Do you ever create an object which two different threads will have a reference to?

Comment: Inheritance has very little to do with thread-safety. However as your member variables are `final` in both `A` and `B`, and there are no member variables in `C` and `D`, those classes are thread-safe so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Thread Safety" thing comes into the picture when multiple threads are trying to manipulate *same object* and by allowing to do so may end up with inconsistent state of the *Object* which is obviously not acceptable for any application.

Your question is about the Object you've declared in your abstract parent class, now as I said earlier the problem will only be there if multiple threads are using the same object, since you're creating new objects every time the service method is getting called, you are safe *why?*, because the scope of the object is limited to the method and multiple threads can not use the same object as for each method call you'll have a different object.

Now consider this case, in this case thread safety is a concern,

```
@Service
class UnSafeClass {

    private MyClass myClassObject;

    public void doSomething() {
        myClassObject.changeData();//Same object will be used by multiple threads
    }
  
}
```

So, your current implementation does not have any thread safety concerns but we should definitely need to clarify on where exactly you need to take care of thread safety.